# Donut, cut on the bottom

Tags: modeling

I am making donut from Blender guru donut tutorial for 3.0 and at one point i noticed strange cut at the bottom.[image]
it looks like this when i bring it up:[image]
I would like to somehow connect it together because, for example, when i do sculpting on this, holes begin to appear.

Comment: Select the whole "ring" on the mesh on either side of the of the "gap" (you already have _one_ selected in the bottom image) right-click and select "bridge edge loops".

Comment: you must have ripped the edge, so either do what Christopher propose or try to select all and press M > Merge by Distance

Comment: I did what @moonboots said and it did exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have somehow ripped the edge (<kbd>V</kbd>), so either do what Christopher proposes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*) if there's a gap between the edges, or, if the edges still stick to each other, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*